# Referencing attribute value in xsl:param xsl:if test condition

Tags: xslt, testing, if-statement, attributes, param

I'm trying to retrieve the attribute value from an xsl:param and use it in an xsl:if test condition.
So given the following xml

```
<product>
  <title>The Maze / Jane Evans</title> 
</product>
```

and the xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="test" select="Jane"/>

 <xsl:template match="title[contains(., (REFERENCE THE SELECT ATTRIBUTE IN PARAM))]">
   <h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
   </h2>
   <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/')"/>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to get back

```
The Maze

Jane Evans
```

Comment: Steven: Apart from the error you have in specifying the parameter, the wanted processing has to be specified differently in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have a problem in this line**:

```
<xsl:param name="test" select="Jane"/>
```

This defines an `xsl:param` named `test`, whose value is the child element of the current node ('/') named `Jane`. As the top element is `<product>` and not `<Jane>`, the `test` parameter has the value of an empty node-set (and a string value -- the empty string).

**You want** (notice the surrounding apostrophes):

```
<xsl:param name="test" select="'Jane'"/>
```

**The whole processing task can be implemented rather easily**:

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTest" select="'Jane'"/>

 <xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(., $pTest)">
       <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
       </h2>
       <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/')"/>
       </p>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<product>
    <title>The Maze / Jane Evans</title>
</product>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<h2>The Maze </h2>
<p> Jane Evans</p>
```

**Explanation**:

The XSLT 1.0 syntax forbids variable/parameter references in a match pattern. This is why we have a single template matching any `title` and we specify inside the template the conditions for processing in a specific, wanted way.

**An XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTest" select="'Jane'"/>

 <xsl:template match="title[contains(., $pTest)]">
   <h2>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
   </h2>
   <p>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/')"/>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), again the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<h2>The Maze </h2>
<p> Jane Evans</p>
```

**Explanation**:

XSLT 2.0 doesn't have the limitations of XSLT 1.0 and variable/parameter references *can* be used within a match pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The term $test refers to the value of the test parameter. Use $test

eg:

```
 <xsl:template match="title[contains(., $test)]">
   <h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
   </h2>
   <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/')"/>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't believe $test refers to the select attribute of xsl:param. I believe it refers to the test value of xsl:param. So, if I had <xsl:param name="test" select="Jane">Jane</xsl:param> then $test will work. However, I can't set that value since I'm using IE and only setattribute function is available.